# excel move result of formula to another colomn

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I need to move the results of formula placed in H8-H22 to colomn C8-C22. How would a piece of VBA code look like to achieve this?

If possible can I do the same thing for multiple sheets at once?

Thanks for any help!
/Rasmus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
range("C8:C22").value = range("H8:H22").value
```

To do the multiple sheets you can either write a simple loop, or else try recording a macro where you select multiple sheets and then copy your "H" range and paste special as values into your "C" range (but all while you have multiple sheets selected)